# Edit distance alike algorithm in recursive

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I was given a task to find the "Edit distance" between array of binary int e.g: 011011 and such

There are 3 options: 1. remove bit from the right 2. remove bit from the left, 3. do nothing

Now if we remove a bit the distance is reduced by 1 and if the bits are matching the distance is increased by one.

So for example: s1=01010101 s2=10101010 we can remove the leftmost bit in s1 (-1) and the rightmost bit in s2 (-1) and get s1=1010101 and s_2=1010101 which is 7-2=5

I am trying to write an algorithm and thought about the following:

```
fun(s1,s2){
    if s1[i] == s2[i]
        score++
    else
        return min(fun(s1[n-1],s2),fun(s1,s2[n-1]),fun(s1+1,s2),fun(s1,s2+1))-1
}
```

How to proceed from here?

Comment: can't you just adapt the classical edit-distance algorithm? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%E2%80%93Fischer_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

You have four options in total remove leftmost bit from `s1`, remove rightmost bit from `s1`, remove leftmost bit from `s2`, remove rightmost bit from `s2`. Try all four oprions and take the minimum. Here is a solution in python using memoization in python.

```
memo = {}
def fun(s1, s2):
    if s1 == s2:
        return 0
    if (s1, s2) in memo:
        return memo[s1, s2]
    r = 1e10 # infinity
    if len(s1) > 0:
        # remove left bit from s1
        r = min(r, 1 + fun(s1[1:], s2))
        # remove right bit from s1
        r = min(r, 1 + fun(s1[:-1], s2))
    if len(s2) > 0:
        # remove left bit from s2
        r = min(r, 1 + fun(s1, s2[1:]))
        # remove right bit from s2
        r = min(r, 1 + fun(s1, s2[:-1]))
    memo[s1, s2] = r
    return r
fun('01010101', '10101010') # 2
```

This can be further optimized by using indices of the substring instead passing the string as argument. Time complexity is `O(n^4)`. The fact that you cannot just insert or remove character from anywhere you want actually makes it complexity higher I think. I think it can be reduced though.